# include variable in partial include string in harp/ejs

Tags: ejs, harp

I'm trying to build a dynamic string that will then include a partial. Essentially, I would like to do something like this:

```
<%= partial("questions/<%= filename %>") %>
```

but that isn't working. Any tips on how do to this?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple string concat!

```
<%= partial("questions/" + filename) %>
```

Thanks to Mike McNiel (creator of Sails.js) for answering this on Twitter.